# Zend framework with dojo

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, dojo, javascript-framework

I'm developing an application with zend framework and i'd like to add dojo framework.
I've done the following :
Bootstrap.php :

```
public function _initViewHelpers()  
{  
    $this->bootstrap('layout');  
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');  
    $view = $layout->getView();

    $view->addHelperPath('Zend/Dojo/View/Helper',
                                    'Zend_Dojo_View_Helper');

    $view->dojo()->enable();  
}
```

my layout.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->doctype() ?>
<html>
    <head>
    <?php echo $this->headTitle() ?>
    <?php echo $this->headMeta() ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink() ?>
    <?php echo $this->headStyle() ?>
    <?php if ($this->dojo()->isEnabled()){
        $this->dojo()->setLocalPath('/js/dojo/dojo.js')
                     ->addStyleSheetModule('dijit.themes.claro');
        echo $this->dojo();
       }
    ?>
    <?php echo $this->headScript() ?>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>
    <?php echo $this->inlineScript() ?>
</body>
```

finally my index.phtml :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    // our test data store for this example:
    var store4 = new dojo.store.JsonRest({
        target: '/guestbook/test'
    });

    storeData =  new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore( 
            { data:store4 }
        ); 

    // set the layout structure:
    var layout4 = [{
        field: 'Title',
        name: 'Title of Movie',
        width: '200px'
    },
    {
        field: 'Year',
        name: 'Year',
        width: '50px'
    },
    {
        field: 'Producer',
        name: 'Producer',
        width: 'auto'
    }];

    // create a new grid:
    var grid4 = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        query: {
            Title: '*'
        },
        store: storeData,
        clientSort: true,
        rowSelector: '20px',
        structure: layout4
    },
    document.createElement('div'));

    // append the new grid to the div "gridContainer4":
    dojo.byId("gridContainer4").appendChild(grid4.domNode);

    // Call startup, in order to render the grid:
    grid4.startup();
});
```

```
<div id="gridContainer4" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>

<?php // setup required dojo elements:
$this->dojo()->enable()
             ->setDjConfigOption('parseOnLoad', true)
             ->requireModule('dojo.store.JsonRest')
             ->requireModule('dojo.data.ObjectStore')
             ->requireModule('dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore')
             ->requireModule('dojox.data.QueryReadStore')
             ->requireModule('dojox.grid.DataGrid')
             ->addStyleSheet('/js/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css')
             ->addStyleSheet('/js/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css'); ?>
```

when i'm trying to access the page localhost/guestbook, the page is rendered but no datagrid, it's like javascript is not enabled...
the url /guestbook/test return a json object.
And in firebug, there is no javascript error, the dojo.js is loaded, the dojo modules and the css too.
I don't understand what is happening !
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the grid and putting it in an unattached div. Instead, attach the grid gridContainer4

```
// create a new grid:
var grid4 = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    query: {
        Title: '*'
    },
    store: storeData,
    clientSort: true,
    rowSelector: '20px',
    structure: layout4
}, 
dojo.byId("gridContainer4"));
```